# Running the Visual Studio Profiler from the command line

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

As part of an automated profiling system, i want to run the visual studio profiler from the command line.

According to all of the online documentation, i need to execute the following:

```
VSPerfCmd \start:sample /output:test.vsp /launch:Test.exe
```

VSPerfCmd is in my system path, and Test.exe is a HelloWorld C++ program compiled with VS2019 and located in the current directory. I am running the 32-bit version of the profiler and Test.exe is a 32-bit application. I get this error:

```
Error VSP1005: Command line error: Switch /launch:Test.exe is invalid. Aborting.
```

One of the guides in found mentioned running

```
VSPerfCLREnv /sampleon
```

before starting the profiler in sampling mode. However my version of the VSPerfCLREnv command does not recognize this parameter. Using the /Admin parameter for VSPerfCmd i installed and started the Profiler service, i am unable to start the kernel driver in the same way, but considering Test.exe is just a HelloWorld program, i don't think i would need it.

Has anyone used the command line profiler in VS2019 and can share how they made it work?

Comment: See the __Example__ here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/launch?view=vs-2019  looks like it needs to be  2 separate commands

Comment: @RichardCritten Running them as two seperate commands gives me the same error for the second command and this for the first: "Error VSP1393: Switch Sample is not a valid value for the START switch. Aborting." But i don't think they have to be run as two separate commands, as they are not in this particular piece of documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/visualstudio/profiling/walkthrough-command-line-profiling-using-sampling?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that VSPerfCmd is no longer useable in Sampling mode in Windows 8 or above.
Instead VSperf is used for sampling and VSPerfCmd for tracing.