# Starting VS2019 and either starting profiler or skipping welcome screen

Tags: c++, visual-studio, command-line, ide, visual-studio-2019

I often use VS 2019 (16.8.5) to profile applications developed with Qt on Windows (10). I've got it configured as an external tool in Qt Creator.

However, every time I open it by just running `devenv.exe`, I have to go through the same process of clicking "Continue with No Code" on the startup welcome screen, then selecting **Debug → Performance Profiler** from the menu. I'd like to automate that as much as possible.

So my question is: **Is there any way, from the command line, to start the IDE, skip that welcome screen, and go straight to the profiler? If not, can I at least skip the welcome screen?**

I looked in [the manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/devenv-command-line-switches?view=vs-2019) but couldn't find anything that seemed to do the job (`/NoSplash` doesn't skip the welcome screen, btw). However, I noticed that the output of `devenv.exe /?` in the console listed a slightly different option set, and also there's the `/Command` switch (which I also read the docs for), and both of these together, combined with past experience, lower my confidence in the completeness of the documentation there. I also found [Running the Visual Studio Profiler from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57604723/running-the-visual-studio-profiler-from-the-command-line) but it discusses using the command-line profiler directly; I want to run the graphical profiler in the IDE, though.

If there's no way via `devenv.exe`, is there maybe some other way to automate this? And if there *is* a way, the bonus question is: Can I go further than just opening the profiler and actually start profiling given an executable filename or a running PID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start VS and open the profiler like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /Command Debug.DiagnosticsHub.Launch
```

Comment: Nice, it's perfect. How did you figure out what `/Command` command to use?

Comment: Oh fwiw after some poking around I found at least a partial list in **Tools -> Environment -> Keyboard**.

Comment: @JasonC Yes, pressing a shortcut in Keyboard options shows the used command name. There is also https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.CommandExplorer

Answer (score -1):

It is easy to configure Visual Studio Code to your liking through its various settings. Nearly every part of VS Code's editor, user interface, and functional behavior has options you can modify.

in order to stop the welcome screen do the following things

> 1. go to File > Preferences > Settings
> 2. search "Startup Editor"
> 3. choose "None" from the drop-down menu

in order to edit / make a new screen when app started follow the below steps

> 1. go to File > Preferences > Settings
> 2. search "Startup Editor"
> 3. choose "NewUntitleFile" from the drop-down menu
> 4. Setup your own file

Comment: Sweet thanks. I'm not using VS Code, I'm using regular Visual Studio. However, thanks for reminding me to check the options there; the VS equivalent is **Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Startup** then selecting "Empty Environment" from the dropdown. So that got me past the startup screen at least. Now to figure out how to start the profiler...

Comment: please fix answer; OP's question is about visual studio, not visual studio code.  They are different programs.